# Webkit Autologin not working using Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")

Tags: vb.net, authentication, webkit, web-scraping

I really need to get this autologin script working with Webkit 0.5 in Visual Basic:

It is intended to run on https://www.ea.com/profile/login

Somehow it doesn't seem to work as I cannot

```
Dim ElementListe As HtmlElementCollection
```

Therefore the following is impossible:

```
For Each Element As HtmlElement In ElementListe
```

Current Code (not mine):

```
Private Sub Load()

    AlleFelderAusgefüllt = False

    Try
        BattlelogBrowser.Navigate("https://www.ea.com/profile/login")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Beep()
    End Try

   Do While BattlelogBrowser.IsBusy = True
       Application.DoEvents()
    Loop

    Dim ElementListe

        ElementListe = WebkitBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")

        For Each Element In ElementListe

            Select Case Element.GetAttribute("name")       
               Case "email"
                    Element.SetAttribute("Value", TextBox1.Text)

                Case "password"
                    Element.SetAttribute("Value", TextBox2.Text)
            End Select
        Next

        For Each Element In ElementListe
            If Element.GetAttribute("value").Equals("Login") Then
                Element.InvokeMember("click")

            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Any solutions? It worked quite similar with the usual Webbrowser, hence I hoped one of you might be able to edit the code or even create a new one!

Regards, RiX

Answer (score 0):

Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to compare what goes over the wire when it works and when it doesn't work... once you know the differences you can change your accordingly...

This way you could be able to achieve what you want without the browser control by using `HttpWebRequest`...

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim doc As WebKit.DOM.Document = WKB.Document
Dim inputs As WebKit.DOM.NodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("input")
Dim inputElement As WebKit.DOM.Element

For Each item As WebKit.DOM.Element In inputs
    inputElement = DirectCast(item, WebKit.DOM.Element)

    Select Case inputElement.GetAttribute("name")
        Case "username"
            inputElement.SetAttribute("Value", txtAccount.Text)

        Case "password"
            inputElement.SetAttribute("Value", txtPassword.Text)
    End Select
Next
```

You can submit form by:

```
For Each item In inputs
    inputElement = DirectCast(item, WebKit.DOM.Element)
    If inputElement.GetAttribute("value").Equals("Login") Then
    WKB.StringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementById('smlogin').click()")
    End If
Next
```